# Using a content Uri for alarm notification

Tags: android, notifications, uri, android-contentresolver

I have given the user the choice of what sound they want in their notifications but can't make it work. It always plays the default sound.  They choose their sound in the preferences

```
 <RingtonePreference
        android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
        android:key="alarmsound"
        android:ringtoneType="notification"
        android:showDefault="true"
        android:summary="Choose Your Alarm Sound"
        android:title="Alarm Sound" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Then it is pulled up in my notification activity

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String alarms = getPrefs.getString("alarmsound", "");
```

This returns a content Uri    content://media/external/audio/media/10

I tried to convert it to a file path
with

```
String filePath = null;
Uri _uri = Uri.parse(alarms);
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String [] { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA }, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
filePath = cursor.getString(0);
cursor.close();
Log.e(TAG5, filePath);
```

This returns  `/storage/sdcard0/Notfications/hangout_ringtone.m4a`

I tried putting this into the `.setSound(filePath);` but it doesn't work. It wants a `Uri` and I know this isn't a full path.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if anyone else will need this but I was able to solve my problem with the help of other stackoverflow posts and the following code.  First I disabled any default sounds in my notification builder

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())


            .setContentText(notificationContent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(notificationTitle)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setSound(null);
```

Setting sound to null removed the default sound. then I added in on the next line

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(alarms)).play();
```

(alarms) is a string that was from my sharedpreferences as seen in my original question.  full implemented code is

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean vibrate = getPrefs.getBoolean("vibrate", true);

    String alarms = getPrefs.getString("alarmsound", "");
    Log.e(TAG4, alarms);




    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())


            .setContentText(notificationContent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(notificationTitle)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setSound(null);


            RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(alarms)).play();        

    if (vibrate == true ){


            notificationBuilder.setDefaults(
                    Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
                            | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    } else {
                notificationBuilder.setDefaults(
                        Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
                                | Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    }
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Comment: above soln worked for as well which is just a quick fix, but I am still in surprised why setSound(soundURI) didnt' worked for me. anybody caught anything stupid in it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will take care of it for you:

```
String alarms = getPrefs.getString("alarmsound", "");
Uri _uri = Uri.parse(alarms);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setContentText(notificationContent)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setTicker(notificationTitle)
        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
        .setSound(_uri);

Notification notification = nBuilder.getNotification();

// Make sure you do *not* include the default sound 
// or the setSound call above will be ignored
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```