# set custom sound for notification

Tags: android, audio, android-notifications

> I'm trying to set custom sound for notification.

**Details:**

I'm trying to set sound of notification by user's choice (from their phone storage).
for that i save path to db and when notification comes about, to show notification and set sound; i fetch sound from exist notification id.

from that i decide which sound should play either sound which user choose or default sound.... but this is not working at All...it playing no sound not even default one.

How to set/play custom sound for notification!?

After google research: many suggestions to play sound from raw folder but i don't get ans by which i save user selected sound to raw folder(of course programmatic ally) so i can play sound from raw folder..

**P.S** there are many ans related to this but they didn't match with my requirement

**Here's my code:**

```
 private void showNotification(Context context, Things things) {

    try {
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                //example for large icon
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon))
                .setContentTitle(things.getTitle())
                .setContentText(things.getThing()).setSubText(things.getNotification())
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context,
                        0,
                        i,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                );
        // example for blinking LED
        mBuilder.setLights(0xFFb71c1c, 1000, 2000);
        if (things.getRingtone() == null || things.getRingtone().equals("")) {
            mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

        } else {
           Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, Uri.parse(things.getRingtone()));
            r.play();
            Toast.makeText(context, things.getRingtone(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(12345, mBuilder.build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "catch  " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: down votes reason?

Comment: @Rucha Bhatt can u ans?

Comment: hi welcome to stackoverflow, here i already tried to help you by editing your question so other can easily understood, i never try before this but i'll try and research something and let you know.. thanx

Comment: thanks for quick reply ..i ll wait

Answer (score 1):

Starting with API 26 (Oreo) you need to set the sound on the notification channel. Once the channel is created its settings including its sound cannot be changed, unless the app is re-installed or the local data has been cleared.

So, the best approach would be to have two (or more) channels- one for each sound/vibration you would like to play.

In code you can decide which channel to use depending on which sound you want to play.

Here is my code where I play either the default notification sound or a custom sound depending on the client's settings. The code also takes care of devices running Android prior to API 26:

```
String sound = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("NotificationsSound", getString(R.string.settingsNotificationSiren));
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.siren);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationChannel mChannel;
String channel_id = Utils.CHANNEL_DEFAULT_ID;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (sound.toLowerCase().equals(getString(R.string.settingsNotificationSiren).toLowerCase())) {
        channel_id = Utils.CHANNEL_SIREN_ID;
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(Utils.CHANNEL_SIREN_ID, Utils.CHANNEL_SIREN_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GRAY);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setDescription(Utils.CHANNEL_SIREN_DESCRIPTION);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
        mChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
    } else {
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(Utils.CHANNEL_DEFAULT_ID, Utils.CHANNEL_DEFAULT_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GRAY);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setDescription(Utils.CHANNEL_DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION);
    }
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel( mChannel );
    }
}

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_maps_local_library)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        .setTicker(title)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setLights(0xff0000ff, 300, 1000) // blue color
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (sound.toLowerCase().equals(getString(R.string.settingsNotificationSiren).toLowerCase())) {
        mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    }
}

int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1; // Causes to update the same notification over and over again.
if (mNotificationManager != null) {
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
    private Uri getSound(){
    String sound = appPreferences.getString(LocalPreferences.PREFERENCE_NOTIFICATIONS_SOUND, "");
    Uri soundUri = null;
    try {
        soundUri = Uri.parse(sound);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}

    if (soundUri == null) {
        soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    return soundUri;
}
```

To put sound to preferences i used this

```
        @Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference){
    switch (preference.getKey()) {
        case LocalPreferences.PREFERENCE_NOTIFICATIONS_SOUND:
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, true);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

            String existingValue = appPreferences.getString(LocalPreferences.PREFERENCE_NOTIFICATIONS_SOUND, "");
            if (existingValue != null) {
                if (existingValue.length() == 0) {
                    // Select "Silent"
                    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, Uri.parse(existingValue));
                }
            }

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ALERT_RINGTONE);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preference);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ALERT_RINGTONE && data != null) {
        Uri ringtone = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        if (ringtone != null) {
            setRingtonePreferenceValue(ringtone.toString());
        } else {
            // "Silent" was selected
            setRingtonePreferenceValue("");
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void setRingtonePreferenceValue(String ringtonePath){
    appPreferences.edit().putString(LocalPreferences.PREFERENCE_NOTIFICATIONS_SOUND, ringtonePath).apply();
    // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
    // using RingtoneManager.
    if (! TextUtils.isEmpty(ringtonePath)) {
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(ringtonePreference.getContext(), Uri.parse(ringtonePath));

        if (ringtone == null) {
            // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
            ringtonePreference.setSummary(null);
        } else {
            // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
            // name.
            String name = ringtone.getTitle(ringtonePreference.getContext());
            ringtonePreference.setSummary(name);
        }
    } else {
        ringtonePreference.setSummary("Без звука");
    }
}
```

Source for second block: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37057453#c2

And of course while building your notification you should call

```
        builder.setSound(getSound())
```

And check if sound enabled on your device.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: this Line **Uri ringtone = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);** Always return null

Comment: if i use above mentions intents it will open list of tones built in the phone correct?  but i want to let the user to choose from anywhere to the device..

Comment: your suggestion did the trick for choosing in built alarm tone not for any audio file but

Comment: Hmm, on my meizu m3 note it allows to choose not only default sounds, but on moto z with vanilla android it really allows choose only from default sounds. I think, that you need to open file manager via startActivityForResult() method and parse returned data. You can create intent like this:   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.setType("*/*");
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); and set mimeType audio/*, but I am not sure that it helps

Comment: And in onActivityResult method you can get uri for returned audio file.  Try to set it as notification sound

Comment: And please check accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475316/using-a-content-uri-for-alarm-notification It shows another path to set custom notification sound